# JSP includes tags for internationalization

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, jsp-tags

I have this structure in my JSP (template.jsp):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<c:set var="language" value="es" scope="session"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.myweb.i18n.text"/>

<html>
  <body>
     <fmt:message key='login.label.username'/>
     <jsp:include page='/home/header.jsp' flush='true'/>
     <jsp:include page='/home/body.jsp' flush='true'/>
     <jsp:include page='/home/footer.jsp' flush='true'/>
  </body>

</html>
```

The fmt:message line works well (print a text label). But if I write this line in header.jsp or any other jsp included does not work.

I must write all tag lib lines in all jsp files?
There any way to include without repeat the firsts 4 lines in all my jsp?

Thanks!

Edit: example header.jsp

```
<div>
   <fmt:message key='login.label.username'/>
   <jsp:include page='/home/header-left.jsp' flush='true'/>
   <jsp:include page='/home/header-center.jsp' flush='true'/>
   <jsp:include page='/home/footer-right.jsp' flush='true'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can include in header and then include the header in all other jsp pages -  I guess, that's what you have tried. It's completely legal. If it's not working then show us header.jsp, how you have included the header.jsp. Try using `<fmt:message key='login.label.username'/>
` after the header is included.

Comment: If I not include taglibs on header.jsp does not work

Comment: If you don't include taglib, how it will work. You can do one thing, put all your taglibs in a common jsp file (eg. header.jsp) and include header.jsp in all other jsp file (eg. home.jsp, administrator.jsp etc). In this way you have to define taglib in only one place.

Comment: Thanks Kartic, I did it. But I was looking a solution with includes on cascade. But I think It not possible.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by includes on cascade?

Comment: Yes. template.jsp -> header.jsp -> header-left.jsp -> and so ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the lines in a jsp & include it in the current jsp i;e template.jsp as

```
<@include file="path/jspcontaininglibs.jsp"/>
<html>
  <body>
     <fmt:message key='login.label.username'/>
     <jsp:include page='/home/header.jsp' flush='true'/>
     <jsp:include page='/home/body.jsp' flush='true'/>
     <jsp:include page='/home/footer.jsp' flush='true'/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I must include jspcontaininglibs.jsp in all jsp

Comment: And this is the correct code to do this? repeat and load taglibs on each jsp. Is this the best solution? Load .properties files several times for the same html

Comment: how are the properties files loading several times for a html? You include it on the top of the jsp when a jsp runs it just runs once. Say you run a jsp A which needs taglibs, the taglibs get loaded. Now if you run another jsp B if it need taglibs it will be loaded again. What's the issue with this

Comment: Because each jsp load the same .properties file.